# How to add Linear Gradient to the Slider

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, slider, linear-gradients

How can I add Linear gradient with these colors "#FF0000, #E9FA00, #22FF01, #00E5FF, #1803FF, #FF00E9, #FF0030" to the Slider component below?

```
<Slider
      style={{ width: '50%', marginLeft: 15, marginTop: -12 }}
      minimumValue={0}
      maximumValue={100}
      value={presetMax}
      step={1}
      thumbStyle={{
      width: 10, // Customize thumb width
      height: 10, // Customize thumb height
      borderRadius: 10, // Make thumb circular
      }}
      trackStyle={{
        height: 2, // Customize track height
        borderRadius: 0, // Make track rounded
      }}
      onValueChange={handleMaxPresetChange}
      thumbTintColor="#0F8D48" // Customize thumb color
      minimumTrackTintColor="#0F8D48"
 />
```

I want the colors to be on track. Also, is there possible to get two thumbs for a min. and max. value? I am using "react-native-elements" for the slider part.

EDIT:
I have implemented the required gradient like this:

```
 <View>
    <LinearGradient
     start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
     end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
     colors={['#FF0000', '#E9FA00', '#22FF01', '#00E5FF', '#1803FF', '#FF00E9', '#FF0030']}
     style={styles.linearGradient}>
     <Slider
      minimumTrackTintColor={'transparent'}
      maximumTrackTintColor={'transparent'}
      thumbStyle={styles.brightThumb}
     />
    </LinearGradient>
 </View>
```

I want to know if I can add another thumb to this slider to represent a min and a max value. Or will I have to use some other library?